# Find table name in all objects of all databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a system with multiple databases and client applications. All databases are at one SQL Server instance. They have been developed by different people at different time. So if some error occur it is pritty hard to find in which procedure or trigger the data was modified.

Now I use this script, which I found on this site:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ISNULL(sd.referenced_schema_name+'.','')+ OBJECT_NAME(sd.referenced_id)TableName,
        OBJECT_NAME(sd.referencing_id)Ref_Object,
        CASE WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsUserTable')= 1
                     THEN'Table'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsTableFunction')= 1
                     THEN'Function'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsTableFunction')= 1
                     THEN'Function'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsScalarFunction')=1
                     THEN'Function'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsTrigger')= 1
                     THEN'Trigger'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsView')= 1
                     THEN'View'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsUserTable')= 1
                     THEN'Table'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsProcedure')= 1
                     THEN'Procedure'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsIndexed')= 1
                     THEN'Index'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsForeignKey')= 1
                     THEN'ForeignKey'
        WHEN OBJECTPROPERTYEX(sd.referencing_id,N'IsPrimaryKey')= 1
                     THEN'PrimaryKey'
        END AS Ref_Object_Name
FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies SD
        INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
                     ON obj.object_id=sd.referenced_id
WHERE   obj.is_ms_shipped= 0
        and referenced_id=object_id('TABLE_NAME') /*Where one can Replace table Name*/
        AND obj.type_desc='USER_TABLE'
        ORDER BY TableName,Ref_Object,Ref_Object_Name
```

But this script seems to work only for the database to which the table belong.

I want to get for a specified table name (or even better for an object) list of all objects of all databases in which the specified table name met:

```
Database_Name  SchemaName  ObjectName  ObjectKind
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME = N'%';



DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT DISTINCT Database_Name = ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''',
        COALESCE(sd.referenced_schema_name +''.'', '''')+ o.name AS TableName,
        r.name AS Ref_Object,
        r.type_desc AS Ref_Object_Name
FROM    ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sd
        INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects AS o
        ON o.object_id = sd.referenced_id
        INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects AS r
        ON sd.referencing_id = r.object_id
WHERE   o.is_ms_shipped =  0
        and referenced_id = o.object_id
        AND o.type_desc = ''USER_TABLE''
        AND o.name LIKE ''' + @table_name + '''
UNION ALL
'
 FROM sys.databases 
 WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766;

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql)-11) 
    + 'ORDER BY Database_Name, TableName,Ref_Object,Ref_Object_Name';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

**EDIT**

The above will find all the references within each database, but won't find cross-database references. It took a little playing, and the output isn't precisely what you wanted, but I think it makes it more self-explanatory:

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME = N'%'; -- find all



CREATE TABLE #d
(
    db SYSNAME, 
    [object_id] INT, 
    sch SYSNAME,
    obj SYSNAME,
    ref_db NVARCHAR(128),
    ref_sch NVARCHAR(128), 
    ref_obj NVARCHAR(128),
    ref_object_id INT,
    type_desc SYSNAME
);

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 'SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''',
    d.referencing_id,
    QUOTENAME(s.name),
    QUOTENAME(o.name),
    QUOTENAME(d.referenced_database_name),
    QUOTENAME(d.referenced_schema_name),
    QUOTENAME(d.referenced_entity_name),
    d.referenced_id,
    o.type_desc
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
    + '.sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
    + '.sys.objects AS o
    ON d.referencing_id = o.[object_id]
INNER JOIN ' 
    + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas AS s
    ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE d.referenced_entity_name LIKE ''' + @table_name + '''
UNION ALL
'
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766;

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql)-11);

INSERT #d EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT 
    db+'.'+sch+'.'+obj, 
    ' (' + type_desc + ') references => ',
    COALESCE(ref_db, db)+'.'+ref_sch+'.'+ref_obj
    FROM #d;
GO

DROP TABLE #d;
GO
```

Sample output:

```
[db1].[dbo].[foo]  (SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE) references =>   [db2].[dbo].[bar]
[db1].[dbo].[xyz]  (SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE) references =>   [db1].[dbo].[table_xyz]
```

Comment: Thank you, Aeron. That's what I wanted.

Comment: But it seems that the script doesn't work if a table name Database_name.schema_name.object_name met in an object of another database.

Comment: @Igor please see the updated answer for a cross-database approach.

Comment: Yes, it works fine. Thank you one more time. You saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you get started

```
create table ##tbData (
DatabaseName Varchar(64),
objectName varchar(128),
ObjectKind varchar(128)
)
go

EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "use [?];
       insert ##tbData select db_name(),so.name,so.xtype from sysobjects so"

select * from ##tbdata
```

Essentially, build a table and the SQL statement you want to use, then use the undocumented sp_MSforEachdb to load the table from every database

Comment: Can't endorse sp_MSforeachdb. Not only because it is not supported or documented, but also because I have seen first hand cases where it breaks. For more details see http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2201 (Also, why a ##global temp table?)

Comment: I chose a global temp table to make sure it can safely be accessed by the stored proc.   you could do the same thing with a fully qualified table name inside the sp_MSforEachDB call

Comment: A normal #temp table will work fine if you insert #t exec ... All a ##global does is make sure that two people can't run this code simultaneously.

Comment: Good point about the temp table and thanks for the link on sp_MSforEachDB().   I use it rarely for one-off requests, I guess after reading that article, I too would write my own if I used it a lot...

Comment: FYI more background on my replacement for sp_MSForEachDB here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/12/29/a-more-reliable-and-more-flexible-sp-msforeachdb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could look at something like [sp_MSForeachdb](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031) and call the above query each of those databases.

Comment: I would write my own sp_MSforeachdb before I would use Microsoft's built-in version. See my comment on @Sparky's answer for more details.

Comment: I was just running with the lazy answer although having never actually used it, I was unaware of the baggage beyond undocumented/supported.