# how to find modified objects for specific databases?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

How did i get the below changes for the specific databases Adventureworksdw,NorthWind as a single result set.

```
-- Modified Tables
SELECT NAME, TYPE, TYPE_DESC, CREATE_DATE, MODIFY_DATE FROM SYS.OBJECTS 
WHERE TYPE ='U' ORDER BY MODIFY_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Question is not very clear, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363430/select-all-databases-in-sysobjects-that-have-a-table-named-mytable-regardless) might help. So use `sp_msforeachdb` or some dynamic-SQL and then filter accordingly for just the DBs you want to hit.

Comment: sp_msforeachdb will give the results for all the databases but i need only for selected databases.

Comment: So only select out the databases you're interested in from the results you obtain by calling `sp_msforeachdb`, or write your own cursor to only hit the DBs you're interested in?

Comment: Yes i have tired it but its giving multiple result sets but i need required databases results as single set hence I have to use it in SSRS.

Comment: If you have tried things and they haven't worked, it's very much worth detailing this in the question - have a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query.

```
SELECT 
    'Adventureworksdw' AS SourceDatabase,
    NAME, 
    TYPE, 
    TYPE_DESC, 
    CREATE_DATE, 
    MODIFY_DATE 
FROM Adventureworksdw.SYS.OBJECTS 
WHERE 
    TYPE ='U' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'NorthWind ' AS SourceDatabase,
    NAME, 
    TYPE, 
    TYPE_DESC, 
    CREATE_DATE, 
    MODIFY_DATE 
FROM NorthWind.SYS.OBJECTS 
WHERE 
    TYPE ='U' 
ORDER BY MODIFY_DATE DESC
```